# C++: Test Speeds of Sorting - Got 0.00's

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I want to test the speed of three algorithms here's my full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

void bubbleSort(int arr[])
{
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int i, j;
    for(i=(length-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {

        for(j =1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j-1]>arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void selectionSort(int arr1[])
{
    int length = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i= 0; i<length-1; i++)
    {
        int min = j;
        for(j = i+1;j<length;j++)
        {
            if (arr1[j]<arr1[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int temp =arr1[i];
        arr1[i]=arr1[min];
        arr1[min]= temp;
    }
}

void insertionSort(int arr2[])
{
    int length = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);

    for(int i=1;i<length; i++)
    {
        int index = arr2[i];
        int j =i;
        while(j>0&&arr2[j-1]>index)
        {
            arr2[j]= arr2[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        arr2[j]= index;
    }
}

using namespace std;

main()
{
    char t = 'f';
    char *t1;
    char **t2;

    int choice;

    vector<int> array;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    printf("%d ", rand());
    array.push_back(rand());
    }
    int *arr = new int[array.size()];
    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), arr);

    int *arr1 = new int[array.size()];
    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), arr1);

    int *arr2 = new int[array.size()];
    std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), arr2);

    int choose;

    do{
    std::cout << "\n\nWelcome to the algortihm tester!\n";
    std::cout << "What algorithm would you like to test?";
    std::cout << "\nChoose: \n1.Bubble Sort\n2.Selection Sort\n3.Insertion Sort\n";
    std::cout << "\nNumber of choice: ";
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        {
        clock_t tStart = clock();
        bubbleSort(arr);
        printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;


        //bubble sort
    case 2:
        {
        clock_t tStart = clock();
        selectionSort(arr1);
        printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        {
        clock_t tStart = clock();
        insertionSort(arr2);
        printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;
    }

printf("\nDo you want to test the other algorithms?:<1-Yes/0-No>: ");
scanf("%d", &choose);
}while(choose != 0);
}
```

But I keep getting 0.00's, I copied three arrays of random variables so that I wouldn't be using a sorted array. It seems that the transfer of the array is the problem? i doubt my PC could sort everything in that instant. A penny for your thoughts? on why I'm getting 0.00?

Comment: It appears you've already developed really poor code formatting habits. You should fix those immediately; properly indenting your code will make it much easier to spot problems.

Comment: Thanks Ken :) Yes ill try to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works like charm

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int size)
{

    int i, j;
    for (i = (size - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j - 1]>arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void selectionSort(int arr1[], int size)
{

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<size - 1; i++)
    {
        int min = j;
        for (j = i + 1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[j]<arr1[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = arr1[i];
        arr1[i] = arr1[min];
        arr1[min] = temp;
    }
}

void insertionSort(int arr2[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 1; i<size; i++)
    {
        int index = arr2[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j>0 && arr2[j - 1]>index)
        {
            arr2[j] = arr2[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        arr2[j] = index;
    }
}

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char t = 'f';
    char *t1;
    char **t2;

    int choice, choose, temp;
    const int  size = 10000;
    int  arr[size], arr1[size], arr2[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = rand();
        arr[i] = temp;
        arr1[i] = temp;
        arr2[i] = temp;
    }

    do {
        std::cout << "\n\nWelcome to the algortihm tester!\n";
        std::cout << "What algorithm would you like to test?";
        std::cout << "\nChoose: \n1.Bubble Sort\n2.Selection Sort\n3.Insertion Sort\n";
        std::cout << "\nNumber of choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            clock_t tStart = clock();
            bubbleSort(arr,size);
            printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;


        //bubble sort
        case 2:
        {
            clock_t tStart = clock();
            selectionSort(arr1, size);
            printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;
        case 3:
        {
            clock_t tStart = clock();
            insertionSort(arr2, size);
            printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }
        break;
        }

        printf("\nDo you want to test the other algorithms?:<1-Yes/0-No>: ");
        cin >> choose;
    } while (choose != 0);
}
```

I think Insertion is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

Your `int arr []` is the same as `int *`. It doesn't carry array size information.

You'll need to pass the number of elements in the array separately.

edit: you're probably getting sizeof( pointer ) = 8 sizeof( element being int ) = 4 yielding a length of 2. Not what you're intending at all.

Comment: Ahhh just as I thought the problem was on the passing of my array. So how do I get the length using sizeof()? sorry for being like this. I'm new to C++. srsly. What did you mean by "pass the number of elements in the array separately"? thankyou so much sir

Comment: Just something like `bubblesort( int * arr, int numElements )`. Calculating it as you have works if you're working with the original array, but passing arrays converts them into pointers to the array automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an unnecessarily convoluted way of creating arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> //setprecision
#define N 10000 

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int p[]);

int main() {

    int i, *p = new int[N]; //create int array named p with N size

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        p[i] = rand();
    }

    clock_t tStart = clock();
    bubbleSort(p);
    cout << "Time taken: " << setprecision(2) << (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" <<endl;

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(int p[]) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = N - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (p[j - 1] > p[j]) {
                temp = p[j - 1];
                p[j - 1] = p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use #define N if you want to dynamically change array size when coding. It's much simpler for testing.

You can use setprecision with cout if you want to set how many digits print. Check it out, it's really nifty: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ It also helps keeping things uniform.

If you want better randoms, you can use srand(time(NULL)); It basically uses system time as a seed to generate random numbers. It's not perfect, but it's a step up.